# String comparison between AlphAlph and clist_item fails

Tags: latex3, xparse, etoolbox

I am trying to compare the results of `AlphAlph` and the indexing of a comma-delimited list. Why does this not work?

MWE

```
%! TEX PROGRAM = pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphalph,xparse,ifthen}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \giveme } { m m }
{\clist_item:nn {#1}{#2}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}{
\edef\first{\AlphAlph{1}\AlphAlph{1}}
\edef\second{\giveme{#1}{1}}
Values\\
\first\\
\second\\

\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{\first}}{\detokenize{\second}}}
    {True}
    {False}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\test{AA,AB,AC,BA,BB,BC,CA,CB,CC}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\detokenize{\first}` stops `\first` expanding and is like `\verb|\first|`  so you are comparing the strings `\first` and `\second`

Comment: also `\giveme` is not expandable

Comment: So how do I expand these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `\detokenize` and make `\giveme` expandable.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphalph,xparse,ifthen}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \giveme } { m m }
 {
  \clist_item:nn {#1}{#2}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
 {
  \edef\first{\AlphAlph{1}\AlphAlph{1}}
  \edef\second{\giveme{#1}{1}}
  \noindent Values\\
  \first\\
  \second\\
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\first}{\second}}
    {True}
    {False}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test{AA,AB,AC,BA,BB,BC,CA,CB,CC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's no need for `ifthen`, of course.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphalph,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
 {
  \noindent Values\\
  \AlphAlph{1}\AlphAlph{1}\\
  \clist_item:nn {#1}{1}\\
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \AlphAlph{1}\AlphAlph{1} } { \clist_item:nn {#1}{1} }
    {True}
    {False}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test{AA,AB,AC,BA,BB,BC,CA,CB,CC}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do find the mix of expl3, primitive (\edef) and ifthen-commands rather curious ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's why I added the second (better) code.

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me from hours of debugging!